# track numbers in array java

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keep track of the lowest numbers in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248725/keep-track-of-the-lowest-numbers-in-an-array)

I am trying to keep track of the lowest numbers in an array. And it works PART of the time and I just can't figure it out why its doing this

```
for (int i = 0; i < candidate.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < candidate.length; j++) {

      if (candidate[j] < candidate[i]) {
        System.out.println(candidate[j]+ " "+candidate[i]);
        if(!tracking.contains(dictionary.get(j))) {
          tracking.add(dictionary.get(j));
          System.out.println(dictionary.get(j));
          writeOut.add(space+dictionary.get(j)+" removed");
        }
        min[i] = j;
      }
    }
}
```

And it works for numbers like

```
       2
       2
       1
       2
       1
```

but not for numbers like :

```
  3
  3
  2
  4
  4
```

for this it gets 2 and three when clearly the lowest number is 2!

Comment: I count 5 { and 4 }. I see a redeclaration of i and weird indentation. This code wasn't supposed to run.

Comment: You have asked that question already: [Keep track of the lowest numbers in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248725/keep-track-of-the-lowest-numbers-in-an-array)

Comment: a person edit it wrongly. I have fixed it

Comment: What`s `dictionary`, what`s `writeOut`, what do you mean by *it gets 2 and three ...* ?

Comment: dictionary = is location of the candidates names and writeOut is what I am using to store the presentation at the end of the whole process they have nothing to do with getting the lowest number in the second example the lowest number is 2 only while in the first one the low numbers are 1

Comment: @sibghatuk - I (*the person*) did **not** edit it wrongly and neither did Lukas (another experienced SO member). The weird indentation and the duplicate for expression was part of your original post. We can roll back to 0, no problem.

Comment: @ lukas eder yes I have and I can't figure it out and people keep thinking I have a homework due or somethings I am just making it for fun and to learn java thats it. I just want to learn how to find the lowest number in an array.

Comment: Guys, relax ;-) He's heading for severe prosecution at his patriarchical university, so let's better help him.

Comment: @sibghatuk what are you tying to do with your code exactly? Find lowest number? Index of lowest number?

Comment: Now in min[i] you get index of last candidate member, lower than candidate[i].

Comment: index of the lowest number and it can be NUMbers if they are the same number

Comment: you mean, if the lowest number is 1, you need indexes of all 1?

Comment: This thread got closed. Lets move to the one you created earlier

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just put your numbers in a

```
TreeSet<Integer> set = ...
```

And retrieve the lowest number with

```
Integer lowest = set.first();
```

But since you **have** to do it with an array because of severe prosecution in your jurisdiction, this is how you can do it:

```
int[] array = ...

// If your array is empty, then you will get MAX_VALUE as a result.
int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i : array) {
    lowest = Math.min(i, lowest);
}
```

Comment: We aren't taught that in the course next year.

Comment: sibghatuk, try Lukas's solution and get the higest mark among your classmates!

Comment: it doesn't work like that if next year I pull out code that the profs hasn't taught u can get kicked out off uni for it. That is why I am trying to learn EVERY possible way to do last years projects

Comment: **EVERY** way? I can imagine millions of algorithms for finding that number ;-) See my updated answer to have an idea

Answer (score 0):

The following method will return <strike>the first</strike> all positions of the minimum value in an integer array as a list. So it will return a list with values `2` and `3` for the input `{4,3,1,1,5}`

```
public static List<Integer> findPositionsOfLowestNumber(int[] values) {
   List<Integer> result = new ArrayList();   // start with an empty list
   int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;   // initial min value
   for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
     if (values[i] < min) {
       min = values[i];
       result.clear();
       result.add(i);
     } else if (values[i] == min) {
       result.add(i);
     }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Kept it simple - try to improve it later by looking at `Math.min` or the enhanced for loop (if you're interested in the lowest value rather then it's position in the array)

Comment: @sibghatuk - yes, it is. It does compile and returns the *position* of the lowest value in the array. Feed it with the sample input and it will return `2` because `values[2]` holds the (first) lowest value.

Comment: @sibghatuk - and yes, this improved version works too.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < candidate.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < candidate.length; j++) {
```

use this instead of what you have used:

```
for (int i = 0; i < candidate.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j < candidate.length; j++) {
```

Comment: no this one took away the 3,3,2 instead of only 2